# Qual a diferença entre Export e Save

Tags: docker

Preciso salvar as alterações que fiz de uma imagem no container, e queria entender a diferença:

```
docker export <CONTAINER ID> > /home/export.tar
docker image save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...] > /home/export.tar
```

Li que os 2 gera um arquivo com a imagem, porém o `save` posso colocar mais de uma image. Entretanto os 2 gera um `.tar` com a imagem.

Gostaria de saber qual dos 2 utilizar, sendo que preciso todas as alterações que fiz no container em uma nova imagem

Comment: Bom, só pelos comandos que você colocou na pergunta, o primeiro é utilizado com containers e o segundo com imagens. Só isso já deve responder muita coisa.

Comment: O `export` não sava os metadados do container pode ser que com o `save` faça isso, so que não achei nada :/

Comment: É como o Woss falou, o `save` vai salvar a imagem (incluindo as camadas, tags), o `export` salva o container (exceto os volumes associados a esse container).... não tem muito o que falar. Pra salvar as alterações do seu container em uma nova imagem usa o export, só atentando para o detalhe dos volumes.

Comment: Se eu puder comentar sobre boas práticas, o ideal é escrever um Dockerfile pra gerar suas imagens novas, ao invés de exportar/salvar :)